# A good PHP IDE to work with Joyent

Tags: php, ide, aptana

I want to start working with Joyent accelerator over PHP. I have been using aptana IDE + Cloud for a year and I'm fed up with it.
Have you some good suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CODA is the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want out of an editor/IDE.

Some of the issues with Aptana and PHP are due to the switch from using a custom version of PHP support to PDT between version 1.5 to 2.0. Aptana Studio 3 instead reverts back to a custom plugin for improved integration and support.

For alternatives, many people use Eclipse + PDT.

Alternately, if you want a paid version, then there is Zend Studio, or perhaps PHPStorm.

Coda, TextMate, and others will behave closer to an editor, and will have limited support for things beyond syntax coloring, and perhaps some validation.